# Adding additional tables to database

Tags: mysql, database

I have was wondering if you could help me with this example to see what is better to implement in my database.

I have two tables:

```
service
---------------------------
id
name
description
price
stock
shipping method
uses

product
---------------------------
id
name
description
price
stock
shipping method
```

Now I was wondering if I should introduce a third table and have three tables like so

```
service
---------------------------
id
sellable_item_id
uses

product
---------------------------
id
sellable_item_id

Sellable_item
---------------------------
id
name
description
price
stock
shipping method
image
```

The reason that I ask is that I am planing of thousands of services and products and as you can see the product will just contain an id and a foreign key to the sellable item.

Now I need to ask is it worth doing this as I need to divide products and services into two different categories so will search through products and services as completely different things.

When searching for products I can't imagine looking through the sellable items and then checking to see if they are a product or service is very efficient. I guess it would be more efficient to search products and then extract the sellable item info with the foreign key link.

Then again the more efficient thing would be to put the sellable info into the product but that then leads back to the question should the data go in another table as it is the same as the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be more efficient in handling queries which only apply for services or products.

Comment: What is yes in regards to? Yes I should duplicate the data?

If so does this not affect the normalization of the table

Comment: Yes you can have three tables as you mentioned.It affects normalization.But normalization is not always the correct thing to do. Having three tables will give high performance for queries that only apply to services or products.

Comment: Okay cool. So for performance I should go for the two tables to get the best performance. If I go for three tables how much do you think this would affect the performance?

Comment: let say you have 1000 products and 1000 services and you need to get the prices and services. If not indexed, when you have 2 tables you go through 1000 records and find. But when you have three tables you need to make join with service table and Sellable table. Join costs much.